# iphone application linking calendar with textfield

Tags: iphone

In my application i want to textField where user can put date. Now for taking date i need calendar so that user select date from it and it automatically fill into textField. 
What would be the best approach to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

UIDatePicker will allow the user to easily select the date.

Answer (score 1):

uidatepicker and take the value changed

Answer (score 1):

I built a fancy `UITextField` class that set up a `UIDatePicker` as its `inputView`. The main value to this is that, when the user taps into the text field, the date picker is brought up where the keyboard would normally be.

```
UIDatePicker *input = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[input addTarget:self action:@selector(update:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
(UITextField *)myTextField.inputView = input;
[input release];
```

Then, in the `-[update:]` method, use an `NSDateFormatter` to set the text in the textfield.

Comment: on nib file i have to link datePicker with textField?

Comment: Can i not use calendar instead of uidatepicker. because i have other textFields as well on the same nib file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'calendar'.`UIDatePicker` is the iOS standard for date choosing/entry, though.

Comment: As for your other text fields, just don't alter their `inputView` property, and they will work as expected.

Comment: As for your nib question, not sure if you can set `inputView` in the nib, but if you can, just drag a `UIDatePicker` object into your nib (but NOT as part of your view heirarchy), link it to the appropriate `UITextField`'s `inputView` (if you can access it as an `IBOutlet`), and set the `UIDatePicker` to send `UIControlEventValueChanged` to your view controller (or wherever you defined the `update:` method).

Comment: i have a form which contains name, age, sex, date etc. textFields. There are so many applications like thomoscook carency convertor application. when somebody fill a form and goes to date there is little calendar icon attached infront of it. when somebody click on that calendar icon a calendar is opened rather then datepicker. i want to put this sort of functionality into my application

Comment: i really appreciate your efforts. But i calendar rather then datepicker scroll wheel

Comment: Ah. In that case, I'm not aware of any built-in, standard controls to do that.